# Removing the Calendar Icon from a MSCRM form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am working with some Date fields in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and want to get rid of the little calendar icon that brings up the date selector. This selector is just too unwieldy for use of dates more than a month old. Any thoughts on how to get rid of it?

Comment: No, but it's unwieldiness may depend on whether users have been shown properly how to use it for more distant dates - if you click on the name of the month at the top it switches to a 3x4 table of months, with a year at the top. You can quickly move forward or back through the years with the arrows, then click the month you want to 'drop into' that month's calendar and choose a date. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple ways (both require adding a JavaScript web resource and using the following code inside of a function which you register as the OnLoad event on the form):

1:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('birthdate')._control._element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style['display'] = 'none';
```

2:

```
var controlID = 'birthdate';
// The icon has the 'img' string appended to the control ID
var imageID = controlID + 'img';
document.getElementById(imageID).style['display']='none';
```

If you want the input to take up the rest of the space you could hide the parent TD cell and then set the colSpan to 2 on the previous TD cell.

Feel free to add null checking ;)

Comment: keep in mind that this customization is not supported, as it is not covered by the API

Comment: Good point ckeller.  I would put #2 into a function which accepts the 'ID' of the control to hide the calendar control for.  Then put that in some web resource which contains your unsupported scripts...  that way you have a nice place to find your evilness later on.